# Serverless AWS Lambdas in a Docker for OnPremises Deployment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, microservices

I am searching for this for a few days, found some approaches like Serverless or Localstack, but what I would really like to do is be able to code everything using AWS API Gateway and Lambdas for a cloud-based version of my software (which is solved) and not manage my deployments.

Then...

A customer wants to host a copy of it inside its own private network, so... I wanna use the very same Lambda code (which makes no use of other AWS 'magic' services like DynamoDB ... only "regular" dependencies) injecting it into a container running "an API Gateway"-like software (perhaps a python/flask parsing the exported API Gateway config?).

I am willing to build this layer unless a better idea shows up. So I would be able to put my lambdas on a folder lets say "aws_lambda", and my container would know how to transform the HTTP payload to an AWS event payload, import the module, call 'lambda_handler' ... and hopefully that is it. Having another container with MySQL and another with Nginx (emulating CloudFront for static website) and I will be done. The whole solution in a can.

Any suggestions? Am I crazy?

Does anyone know some existing software solution to solve this?

Comment: Perhaps this https://pypi.org/project/swagger-parser/ with Flask, FlaskAPI, Hug ... Dynamically creating all routes inside the web engine, pointing with dynamic imports to designated "lambdas"...

Comment: So you want to code onetime and use that code on any provider? Perhaps with some adapters for each provider?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu I can even isolate the lambda handler from my internal business logic (what I usually do even for regular lambdas), but the point is how traffic flows in dynamically mimicking API Gateway, and forward those AWS event objects. It would be only AWS (for cloud) or Docker (for local). No other providers needed...

Comment: @Serge Will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Besides different serverless plugins and localstack you can try AWS SAM Cli to run local api gateway . The command is start-api https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/test-sam-cli.html . It probably would not scale, never tried myself and it is intended for testing.

Curiosly what you are consider to do (transform lambda into normal flask server is oppozite to zappa, which is serverless package that convert normal flask server into a lambda function and uploads it to AWS). If you succed in your original idea of converting a flask request into lambda event and care to package you code, it can be called unzappa. While zappa is mature and large package, probably it would be easier to 'invert' some light-weight thing like awsgi [https://github.com/slank/awsgi/blob/master/awsgi/**init**.py](https://github.com/slank/awsgi/blob/master/awsgi/__init__.py)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use [AWS SAM](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/), the [AWS SAM CLI](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/) offers what you're looking for.

The AWS SAM CLI implements its own API Gateway equivalent and runs the AWS Lambda functions in Docker containers. While it's mainly intended for testing, I don't see any reason, why you shouldn't be able to use it for your use-case as well.

Comment: I saw it designed for testing, but for a low load usage in a private network, I also cant think of a reason to not use it. I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

@Lovato, I have been using https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda Which is a docker image that mimics lambda environment, lambci seems to be maintaining a good version of the lambda images for nodejs, java, python, .net and even go lang. So you can technically reuse your entire lambda code in a docker running lambda "like" environment. I call it lambda-like mostly because aws doesn't fully publish every piece of information about how lambda works. But this is the nearest approximation I've seen. I use this for local development and testing of lambda. And I have tested a trail "offline" lambda. Let me know if this works for you.

I do prefer to use the docker files and create my docker images for my use.